# How to do a whereKey so it querys posts ___ km+ AWAY from currentuser?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

```
var limitlocation = 5 as Double

if let usergeo = currentuser.objectForKey("location") as? PFGeoPoint {
    query.whereKey("location", 
          nearGeoPoint: usergeo, 
          withinKilometers: limitlocation) 
}
```

currently have that but it gets users that are within 5 km. how do i make it so it is 5 km+ AWAY.

Comment: I don't believe that is currently possible to do that with Parse's SDK. You could optionally use the range instead of `withinKilometers` and set it from 5 to X kilometers, if you are able to set a limit for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

By default this type of query will only allow you to query geoPoints that are within 100 miles of the geoPoint you are querying for : https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#geopoints-caveats.

What you can do is filter the results and remove any results that are within 5km.

This is how it would look in objective-c - you'll have to translate this into swift

```
NSMutalbeArray* mutableObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
PFGeoPoint* userGeoPoint = user[@"geoPoint"];
for (PFObject* object in objects) {

    PFGeoPoint* objectGeoPoint = object[@"geoPoint"];
    CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:userGeoPoint.latitude longitude:userGeoPoint.longitude];
    CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:objectGeoPoint.latitude longitude:objectGeoPoint.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB]; // Distance in meters
    if (distance >= 5000) {
        [mutableObjects add:object];
    }

}
```