# How to query with parse.com content MORE than x miles away?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I tried various things and couldnt get it to work. Currently I have this code:

```
var limitlocation = 5 as Double

if let usergeo = currentuser.objectForKey("location") as? PFGeoPoint {
    query.whereKey("location", 
          nearGeoPoint: usergeo, 
          withinKilometers: limitlocation) 
}
```

that queries content within 5 miles of the user. How would I make it so it queries content at least 5 miles away from the user? So the user's geolocation is stored, and when a user is posting content, that geolocation is saved with the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the swift for it, but create two queries: one that you already have, and another, query2, with the same object type, and use the `wherekey:key1 doesNotMatchKey:key2 inQuery:query` method.  key1 and key2 should both be objectId, and query should be the first query you already have.  That will return all objects that were not returned by the first query.

http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:inQuery:

edit - Fixed the link to go to the correct method.  Also, I'd like to point out that this query is still limited to 1000 results. I'm not sure what your use case is, but you may want to think of an additional way to filter these results so that you're getting the most relevant data and not 1000 semi-random ones that happen to be more than 5 km away.

Comment: thanks, that is the best (easiest) solution so far. ill go with this.

Answer (score 0):

This feature doesn't exist in Parse.com's SDK - here is the PFQuery class reference: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html.

What you can do is do a normal query and filter out locations that are within 5 miles of the user, as I explained in your question here: [How to do a whereKey so it querys posts ___ km+ AWAY from currentuser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756263/how-to-do-a-wherekey-so-it-querys-posts-km-away-from-currentuser).

Parse also has a method for calculating the distance between two geoPoints: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFGeoPoint.html#//api/name/distanceInMilesTo:.